# how to fix certificate error in smart phones

Tags: php, ssl-certificate, smartphone, digital-certificate, mobile-website

i have developed mobile site using php with smarty. for live site, in smart phone, all https pages shows certificate errors like "Security Warning .There are problems with the security certificate for this site .The name of the site does not match the name on the certificate".
how to get rid of this issue. please any one help me.

thanks in advance.

Comment: does the name of the site match that or the  certificate?

Comment: Use a certificate with the correct name for the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can buy a certificate for your site from Certificate Authorities(CA) like Verisign, Thawte, Geotrust, Comodo, GoDaddy, GlobalSign, etc. That will solve your issue.